# Generalizing the Weierstrass Preparation Theorem to formal power series in multiple variables

Tags: formal-power-series

The statement of the Weierstrass Preparation Theorem is as follows:

Let $f = \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_iX^i \in K[[X]]$ for some field K where $a_h \neq 0$ and for every $n < h$, $a_n = 0$. Then the elements 1,$\bar x$, ... , $\bar x^{h-1}$ form a basis in $K[[X]]/(f)$ over $K$.

My question is how does one generalize and prove this statement for a ring of formal power series in n variables?

Comment: You can replace $K$ by a complete local ring $A$ (for $n < h$, the $a_{n}$ should be contained in the maximal ideal of $A$), see for example [these notes](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~hochster/615W07/L04.04.pdf) by Hochster. Thus you can apply this to $A = K[[X_{1},\dotsc,X_{r-1}]]$ and use that $(K[[X_{1},\dotsc,X_{r-1}]])[[X_{r}]] \simeq K[[X_{1},\dotsc,X_{r}]]$.